# Cris installation over existing Dspace: not working

Tags: dspace

I am new on this so please do bear with me:)

I installed Dspace on Windows and all was (eventually) working as it should. I am now trying to install the CRIS part and I followed the instructions on https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACECRIS/Installation#Installation-UpgradeanexistentDSpaceinstallation

I start TomCat and Dspace and no changes on the home screen and cannot access any of the CRIS admin pages so I am guessing that whatever I did, was not correct.

Can someone help!!!

I am not a coder/ developer/ etc..

Cheers
N

Comment: Stackoverflow is more for developers. So your question is going to be downvoted as it does not follow what we could call 'stackoverflow standards'. As in no, no code-examples + your question is about general software. You could try to ask the question here ;-) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dspace-tech

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure to have copied the new packaged webapps (jspui, oai) to the tomcat webapp folder? check if the webapps running inside your tomcat have the right timestamp, verify to have some dspace-cris-*.jar in the deployed jspui/WEB-INF/lib etc.

You can also check if your database has been updated: check for the existence of tables named cris_xxxx